# Unable to start receiver crash for widgets on Android 4.0.4 device

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I am experiencing a crash for my widget on a Motorola Xoom running Android 4.0.4.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.chaitanya.widgets.MyWidgetProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2126)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.widget.RemoteViews$SetOnClickPendingIntent.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:436)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:1655)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.updateAppWidgetIds(IAppWidgetService.java:435)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:247)
09-24 15:03:33.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:270)
<my code that calls updateAppWidget>
```

My code listens to certain broadcasts from my app and updates the widget view dynamically. In the process, it removes some of the existing Views (sets to `Visibility.GONE`), and clears PendingIntents by setting them to `null`. After all this, it calls `AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()`.

Now, this works perfectly fine on a 4.1.2 device and on a 4.3 device, but there's this crash on the 4.0.4 device. I have searched a lot, and experimented a lot with Intent options, but I am unable to resolve this. Has anyone experienced this? Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the source code for RemoteViews.java on [4.0.4](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr1-release/core/java/android/widget/RemoteViews.java#L433) and [4.1.2](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/RemoteViews.java#L467), we can see that the 4.0.4 version of `SetOnClickPendingIntent.writeToParcel()` method will crash with a null `pendingIntent`. You can see [this change in the frameworks](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/c6151f2369d92e7725d30d13c62b64cff49285a6) that apparently was committed to address it.

For your case, would it be possible in your code to avoid setting the pending intents to null? Maybe you can use a special value instead for the intent action that can be ignored?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was doing something similar in my appwidget, sending nullified PendingIntents in some cases and the whole update crashed on pre-JellyBean versions. I still needed those nulls so I added `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)` to decide whether go generate those PendingIntents. Previous Android versions lost the related capability of course.

Answer (score 1):

This might help others to prevent the NPE on a widget for Android < 4.1.
It's used to disable the "onClick" on a notification:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetIcon, null);
} else {
    // Android < 4.1
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetIcon,
        pendingIntent);
}
```